# Polling an SFTP server to list files in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparative-review, ssh, scope

When is it better to instantiate the `sftp` client globally vs inside a function as shown below? What considerations favor one method over the other?

For a long running service that polls indefinitely, would it better to instantiate globally so I don't need to instantiate a new client on each run?

Also, is there any difference between using Bluebird's `Promise.delay(10000)` as opposed to wrapping `setTimeout` like so:

`const timeout = async (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));`

Finally, my polling function sleeps at the beginning of the function instead of at the end so my `finally` block frees up the sftp connection without having to wait `10000ms`. Seems okay with the current recursive setup but I'm curious if there are "better" ways to write a recurring task.

Instantiate globally

```js
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const sftp = new Client();

const listFiles = async (directory) => sftp.list(`/${directory}`);

const pollSftpServer = async () => {
  try {
    await Promise.delay(10000);
    await sftp.connect({
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: '2222',
      username: 'foo',
      password: 'pass',
    });
    const files = await listFiles('upload');
    console.log(files);
    return pollSftpServer();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('caught error', e);
    return pollSftpServer();
  } finally {
    sftp.end();
  }
};

(() => {
  pollSftpServer();
})();
```

Instantiating inside a function

```js
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const listFiles = async (sftp, directory) => sftp.list(`/${directory}`);

const pollSftpServer = async () => {
  // Instantiate here?
  const sftp = new Client();
  try {
    await Promise.delay(10000);
    await sftp.connect({
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: '2222',
      username: 'foo',
      password: 'pass',
    });
    const files = await listFiles(sftp, 'upload');
    console.log(files);
    return pollSftpServer();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('caught error', e);
    return pollSftpServer();
  } finally {
    sftp.end();
  }
};

(() => {
  pollSftpServer();
})();
```

Comment: These examples look a bit contrived. Code Review questions should contain real code from a project — see the [help/on-topic] and [ask]. What do you intend to do with the resulting file lists? Can you clarify the intended behavior when `listFiles()` fails?

Comment: @200_success, this function's end goal would be to poll an Sftp server and download any new files. So once I get the file list, I would check the last modified time of each file and decide what to do from there. If `listFiles()` failed, it should enter the `catch` block and poll the sftp server again after waiting another 10s.